# how set border-bottom only for any divs

Tags: html, css

I have problem with set border-bottom

I have sth like this..

```
<article>
  <a></a>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</article>
```

But counter divs in article is variable. I need border-botom on div only when other div follow.
So when I have one div, no border needed. When I have two divs, only first div have border. When I have three divs, only first and second has border... How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
article div:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; /* or whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly the selector I need

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly this is what you are trying to achieve:

**HTML**

```
<article>
  <a></a>
  <div>First</div>
</article>

<article>
  <a></a>
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
  <div>Third</div>
</article>

<article>
  <a></a>
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
  <div>Third</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article{
  margin: 20px;
}
article div{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
article div:last-of-type{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

**Relevant part:**

```
article div:last-of-type{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only divs, you may just check for being the last child or last of type:

```
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
div:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

If you have divs and other elements and want borders only between divs, then I'd suggest using border-top instead and the `+` combinator (adjecent sibling selector):

```
div + div {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Unfortunately it matches only the following div, and not the followed one, thus `border-top` use.

Answer (score 0):

Hum. Think out the box. Try to fix a border-top on the next div just after a div ?

```
article div + div {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

maybe ?